# frm-40735:when mouse click trigger raised unhandled exception ora-06502

Tags: oracle, error-handling, exception, oracle10g, oracleforms

this is my code i wrote for when_mouse_click trigger on a button

```
declare 
a varchar2(20) := '&book_no';
b varchar2(20) := '&book_name';
c varchar2(20) := '&price';
d number(4) := '&no_of_books';
begin
insert into book
values (a,b,c,d);
EXCEPTION
when VALUE_ERROR then
dbms_output.put_line('VALUE_ERROR exception raised');
end;
```

it compiled sucessfully but when i run it says :

> `frm-40735`:when mouse click trigger raised unhandled exception
>   `ora-06502`

but when i display error it says

> no errors encountered recntly

at the same time i run this query on my sqlplus it runs sucessfully.
plz give me a solution soon i wil b very grateful to you .

Answer (score 2):

This is **Forms**; if you meant to use the ampersand (&) like in SQL*Plus, well, you're very wrong as Forms don't work that way. You should create form **items**, let users populate their values, and then store those values into the database.

The error you got is because you're inserting strings into some number columns; the most obvious is the PRICE - that is, most probably, a NUMBER data type column, and you're putting &price into it, literally.

The most usual way is to use the Data Block Wizard, base the block on the BOOK table, and Forms would create *everything* for you - you'd just run the form, put some values into those items and commit.

The way you're doing it now, it seems that you want to use a *control* block, i.e. the one that isn't based on an underlying database object (such as a table or  a view), so you have to create your own INSERT logic - I'd suggest you not to do that. But, if you insist, then the trigger would look like this:

```
begin
  insert into book
    values (:a, :b, :c, :d);

EXCEPTION
  when VALUE_ERROR then
    message('VALUE_ERROR exception raised');
    raise form_trigger_failure;
end;
```

- reference items with the colon sign (I'd also suggest you to always reference them using the block and the item name, such as `:block.item_name`)
- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE won't work in Forms